# After logging in, screen goes blank and then gets distorted?

Tags: 13.10

I used UNetBootin to install Ubuntu 13.10 onto an HP m8100n PC.
It installed perfectly then asked me to reboot to start using it.
I reboot the PC and logged in, but once I had logged in, the screen went blank...
then showed up distorted. This is the first time I've tried Linux overall so, I don't know much about 'tinkering'...
I tried to see if opening terminal would work but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to be a graphic card issue, and acording to the informations I found about your PC, you may have a Nvidia graphic card.

http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ca/en/ho/WF06b/12132708-12133156-12133158-12133158-12133158-80230858-80444148.html?dnr=2

Open a console by pressing these keys together: [ctrl] [alt] [f1]. Log in. Then, install manually the driver with the following command. Your computer must be connect on Internet.

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

sudo reboot